# Is it possible to iterate through an array that is passed to a function?

Tags: c++, arrays

Is there some way to pass an array as an object (as opposed to passing it as a pointer to its first element) and without using a [structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7634337/how-do-i-pass-an-array-function-without-using-pointers)? I want to be able to iterate through the array like this:

```
int get_max(int a[]){
    int max = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]); i++){
        if (a[i] > max) max = a[i];
    }
    return max;
}
```

Comment: Are you aware of `std::array` or `std::vector`? If you cannot use either of those for some reason, then the canonical way to do this is to pass in both the array and the number of elements `int get_max(int a[], std::size_t count)`

Comment: `int a[]` as a function argument becomes `int *a`. So no.

Comment: @CoryKramer I only want to pass the array, without passing another argument (such as its size).

Comment: @icecream2727 you can't. The information of size gets lost at the moment the array is passed to a function (and becomes an int* as rustyx mentioned), thus `sizeof` won't give you the size of the array.

Comment: @user1810087 I see. So ```sizeof(a)``` would be the size of the pointer to the first element in ```a```, and ```sizeof(a[0])``` would be the size of the first **integer** in ```a```. Right?

Comment: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/qVDEjP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For raw arrays, you can pass the array by reference to preserve the size information (which is lost in [array-to-pointer decay](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array#Array-to-pointer_decay)), and make the function template for arbitrary length arrays. e.g.

```
template <size_t S>
int get_max(int (&a)[S]) {
    int max = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]); i++) {
    // or
    // for (size_t i = 0; i < S; i++) {
        if (a[i] > max) max = a[i];
    }
    return max;
}
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/PcgF9CSxxAOjR1t6)

Comment: I've tried that on MSVC 15.9.15 with two arrays of different sizes (5 & 7 elements), compiling for release x64, and the compiler created two subroutines from the template, one for 5 elements, and another for 7. Somehow, I doubt this is the desired result in this case.

Comment: @UriRaz Yes, see [template instantiation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template#Function_template_instantiation).

Comment: @songyuanyao : While this is a nice trick, it probably is worth mentioning that this could lead to code bloat, since every time `get_max` is called with a different array size, a new function is created.